# How to find parent node of a row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

From following html

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="article0">
        <td id="CheckboxDiv0">
            <div class="checkbox">  
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="CheckboxArticle0" value="helo">
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to get the parent id

```
$ParentId = $("#checkboxArticle0").parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
```

The code is not working fine. Can someone suggest me how to grab the id of the parent div which is "article0"?

Comment: `#article0` isn't a `div` and it isn't the parent.

Comment: oh sorry for that mistake just a beginner with jquery@Turnip

Comment: why did you add java tag, its javascript for Christ Sake ! @tmg !dilkush

Comment: @TilakMadichetti I am sorry I did not add that tag but I should have had removed it

Comment: that's fine @TilakMadichetti

Comment: Alright Now its proper and let Go ! XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .closest()

```
var parentId = $("#CheckboxArticle0").closest("tr").attr("id");
```

Description:

The `closest()` method returns the first ancestor of the selected element.
Refer: [This for more.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp)

Comment: am getting the answer as "undefined"  if i use your code @dhara parmar

Comment: do you have the same html structure which you mentioned above?

Comment: @Dilkush: then it should work properly. are you calling the code after dom is ready?

Comment: @Dilkush yes it should be in document.ready as mentioned by milind

Comment: @MilindAnantwar there was a small mistake in camel casing now it's working fine thanks

Comment: @Dilkush: you haven't... :)

Comment: i gave a up vote but due to low reputation it's not getting counted am sorry for that.. i have received much down vote over the question ..

Comment: hope u got now @MilindAnantwar

Comment: @Dilkush: you don't need reputation for accepting answer. You need it for upvote and downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$("#checkboxArticle0").closest("tr").attr("id")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#checkboxArticle0").parents('tr').attr("id")
```

Answer (score 1):

2 points to be note:

1) Use document.getElementById in javascript to access any element using its id,

2) You have mentioned wrong id , Use "CheckboxArticle0" instead of "checkboxArticle0"  (C need to be capital letter)

Correct script is:

```
var ParentId=document.getElementById("CheckboxArticle0").parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
alert(ParentId)
```

Comment: Its enough of Editing a million times~!

Comment: thanks @Jayesh Chitroda that works fine with me but can u suggest me who to achieve the same using jquery

Comment: for jquery : var ParentId = $("#CheckboxArticle0").closest("tr").attr("id");